# What's the recommend way of restoring only parts model in distributed tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, resuming-training

When we finetune a model on a different task, only a part of vars in the model are restored from the pretrained task and others are left as initial values.

As many docs recommends([page1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim) [page2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_train.py)), when training with a local graph, restoring the pretrained model after running the global init op(call restoring in "init_fn" if MonitoredSession or supervisor is included).

But in the distributed case, does global init op **make "model_ready" returns true before the restoring-model called**? other non-chief nodes will use the "not ready" values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out.
global_variables_initializer is in facet variable_initializers(global_variables()). So we can initialize only some selected vars and restore the lefts from pretrained models.
"model_ready" will keep as False until all vars are restored.